# Android New Facebook SDK Exception in Graph Request

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
if (currentSession.isOpened()) {

        Request req = new Request(currentSession, "/me/friends?fields=id,name,installed,picture",null, HttpMethod.GET,
                new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) 
            {
               //CODE..
            }
        });
        Request.executeBatchAsync(req);
}
```

Got response like this.

```
{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 2500, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.}, isFromCache:false}
```

Whats wrong with this code.

Permission provided are
"publish_stream","user_likes","email","user_birthday","user_interests","user_friends"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the result.Thanks @Jesse Chen

```
Bundle params() = new Bundle();
params.putString("fields", "id,name,installed,picture");
Request req = new Request(session, "me/friends", params, HttpMethod.GET..
```

Comment: For me, doing this way the error has disappeared. But the data in JSON is empty, whereas in summary it is returning number of my friends correctly but no data.. Any suggestions?

Comment: @SwapnilPatil: Could you resolve the issue? I am still getting the data array as empty

Comment: @Sunny: Could you please tell me how to resolve the empty array issue? I am getting an empty data array when using this format.

Comment: @BhargavJhaveri I didn't use Bundle to pass parameters. I used another way, which worked for me. Created a new request like below and executed it.
`new Request(session, "me/friends?fields=id,name", null, null, new Request.Callback()  `
  `{ ` 
   `public void onCompleted(Response response) { // Your logic }  `
  `});  `
  
  `// Execute above request`

Comment: @SwapnilPatil Do you get the list of all the friends? Because when I installed the application on another device, I came to know that, it only returns the friends who are also using the same application. Not all.